# object constructor, pass info from the form to the HTML

Tags: javascript, object, event-listener

Fairly new to Javascript. I want to create a library with objects. I have a button in HTML(btnNew) which I click on, opens a form (via eventListener), and I get to type information about books. After I fill in the information, I click the addBtn and again via eventListener, I want it to display the information to a div with class "books", however it fails to do so and whatever I do the info appears as [object HTMLInputElement] for all 4 info. I cannot understand what is the problem. Any help? Thank you

HTML

```
<div class="books">
    </div>
    
    <button class="btn-new">NEW BOOK</button>
    <div id="show-form">
        <form id="form" action="/script.js">
            <div id="textInput">
                <p><input type='text' id='title' name='title' placeholder='Title'></p>
                <p><input type='text' id='author' name='author' placeholder='Author'></p>
                <p><input type='text' id='pages' name='pages' placeholder='Pages'></p>
                <p><input type='text' id='read' name='read' placeholder='Read or Not Read'></p>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" form="submit" id="addBtn">ADD +</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <button id="close-form">CLOSE FORM</button>
```

Script

```
const btnNew = document.querySelector(".btn-new");
const showForm = document.querySelector("#show-form");
const closeForm = document.querySelector("#close-form");
btnNew.addEventListener("click", () => (showForm.style.display = "block"));
btnNew.addEventListener("click", () => (closeForm.style.display = "block"));

const addBtn = document.querySelector("#addBtn");
addBtn.addEventListener("click", addBookToLibrary);

const form = document.querySelector("#form");

function Book(title, author, pages, read) {
  this.title = title.form.value;
  this.author = author.form.value;
  this.pages = pages.form.value;
  this.read = read.form.value;
}

let myLibrary = []
let newBook;

function addBookToLibrary() {
  showForm.style.display = "none";
  closeForm.style.display = "none";

  newBook = new Book(title, author, pages, read);
  myLibrary.push(newBook);
  render();

  form.reset();
}

function render() {
  myLibrary.forEach((newBook) => {
  const newElement = document.createElement("article");
  newElement.innerHTML = `
  <p> ${newBook.title} </p>
  <p> by ${newBook.author} </p>
  <p> ${newBook.pages} pages</p>
  <p> ${newBook.read} </p>
  `;
  document.querySelector(".books").appendChild(newElement);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find several problems in your code (assuming that is the whole code.)

First, in line   `newBook = new Book(title, author, pages, read);`, four variables `title, author, pages, read` don't seem to be defined.

This is same for `render` function. I wonder how are they executed without error.

However, it seemed to have excuted somehow.  `[object HTMLInputElement]` means that `title, author, pages, read` were not number|string. but some kind of object.

My guess is that some code that were excluded from this question, `title, author, pages, read` were defined as html elements. However you should read their value (ie. `author.val()`) instead of the object itself.

You attempted to put 4 js objects into an html element, so they appear as   `[object HTMLInputElement]`  to you.

PS. `this.` in your Book function suggests to me that you were intending to make a Class instead of function. (just guessing)

Comment: the Book function is a function constructor, not a class or a regular function and what I am trying to do in the line  newBook = new Book(title, author, pages, read); is to create an object with these 4 values that will be taken by the form and displayed in the HTML. I updated the render function with something that is now giving undefined when I fill in the form. How can I pass the info I add in the form to the HTML?

Comment: @StavAk Then the problem seems to lie in the ```title.form.value``` part of the code. Try checking it by console.log to make sure it is string, not undefined.

Comment: that was indeed the issue. I removed the .form.value from the constructor and I added .value in the newBook = new Book (title.value etc etc etc). Thanks for your time

Comment: Good to know that helped! Maybe you can accept my answer too :)